# Change text color within highlight effect, Rails, jQuery UI, CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

**Original Question:**
I am able to successfully change the background color within the highlight effect, but I also want to change the text color.  Strangely enough: it appears that the color property in this context refers to the background color, not the text color:

```
$newBlogger.effect('highlight', {color: '#DFF2BF'}, 2000)
```

How do I also specify the text color so that can be changed as well during the effect?

**Answer:** Along the way I realized I could use dequeue( ) to make both the highlight effect and the animation effect occur simultaneously.

```
$newBlogger = $('<%= j render(@blogger) %>').css("color", "#4F8A10").hide()
$("#all_bloggers").append($newBlogger)
$('#new_blogger').fadeOut "fast", ->
    $newBlogger.effect('highlight', {color: '#DFF2BF'}, 1500)
    $newBlogger.animate({"color": "black"}, 1500).dequeue()
    $('#new_link').fadeIn("fast").dequeue()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the default `color` option for the hightlight effect will only change the background color. You could try adding `.css` on the end:

```
$newBlogger.effect('highlight', {color: '#DFF2BF'}, 2000).css("color", "Blue");
```

That would change the color of the text.

Alternatively, you could have a css rule and add the class using jQuery:

```
change-color {
    color: Blue;
}

$newBlogger.addClass("change-color");
$newBlogger.effect('highlight', {color: '#DFF2BF'}, 2000);
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/28mdnga8/)

Or, you could use [animate()](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) - something like:

```
$newBlogger 
    .animate({
        backgroundColor: "#DFF2BF",
        color: "#fff"
    }, 1000)
    .animate({
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        color: "#000"        
}, 1000);
```

[animate example](http://jsfiddle.net/28mdnga8/2/)

Comment: That gets me really close.  What I want to do in this situation is to change the text color to "Blue," which the code above now does, but then along with the highlight effect, transition that text color from blue back to the original color: black.  Any ideas?

Comment: you might want to look at http://api.jquery.com/animate/ - I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Neil I've updated my answer with an animate suggestion.